# How to unit test dot42 class library?

Tags: c#, android, unit-testing, dot42

I have create an android library in VS. I would like to test it, however my Unit Test project doesnt seem to be quite compatible with it as it shows a yellow warning triangle :

[image]

In the actual test class I am seeing red squiggles with this message:

[image]

When I add the dot42 dll, it then does not recognise even what a `double` is... So the question is, is there a way to unit test, using MSTest or NUnit etc, any c# assemblies created as dot42 projects?